# How do I use getContents to take input from the command line?

Tags: haskell

My program allows the user to specify a file which is read as input, however this is optional.  If the user does not specify a file, I'd like to read input in from the command line.

I have this so far:

```
main :: IO()
main = do
  (opts, mbArgs) <- parseCmdLine
  input <-
    case mbArgs of
      Nothing   -> getContents
      Just file -> readFile file
```

This doesn't seem to be working.  When a user doesn't stipulate a file, they are able to enter input, but there seems to be no way of terminating so that the program can then work on that input.

I thought that you had to press Ctrl+D, but that doesn't do anything.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you using Windows, Mac or Linux? It depends on the terminal that you use which key sequence you have to use to insert an "End of File" character.

Comment: I'm using Cygwin on Windows... Just to confuse you.

Comment: Use Ctrl-Z and Enter instead of Ctrl-D, it works on Cygwin for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a typical Unix-like terminal (such as Cygwin, at least in Cygwin's `rxvt`; not sure about the Windows Command Prompt), a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> only sends EOF when you're at the start of a line. If you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, it should work. If you want to send EOF without a newline, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> twice in a row.

If it's not that, then there's presumably some other problem with your terminal; the code looks fine.

Comment: IIRC, in the Windows Command Prompt, it's `Ctrl+Z` followed by `Enter`. I don't remember if it has to be at the start of a line or not.

Comment: I can confirm that it has to be on a new line.

Comment: Ctrl-Z followed by Enter works with Cygwin bash running in the Windows terminal.  With Mintty this doesn't work, at least not in the default configuration.  I couldn't get Mintty to work with any of the above suggestions. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to write hammar's comment as an answer.

For me on windows, hitting `ctrl+Z` `crtl+Z` `enter` worked.